# Create a list not that random

Tags: python, list, random

My question is about creating a semi random list of letters in Python. I want that 20% of the time, the letter is the same than 2 letters before.

I do not want only random because if I do so it will not happen 20% of the time that n-2 is the same letter.

I was thinking about creating a first list with the letter I want and then create a new list that will take the letter from the first list but randomly,  but I do not know how to add my constraint of 20%?

**Finally I need it to be exactly 20% of the time**

A
B
B
C
**B**
A
A
C
**A**

Like that for example... Do you have tips for me ?

Comment: let Python give you a random number (by default in the 0-1 range) and if that number is between 0-0.2 repeat the letter from 2 indexes back; if not get a new, random one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Comment: That's actually an interesting problem. I thought: Just create a random list, select 20% of indices and make those same to two before, but that could give you more than 20% same. E.g. you have `[1,0,0,0,1]` and make the middle `0` to a `1`, you get _two_ additional same elements instead of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from random import random, choice

letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']
prob = 0.2
target_length = 20

target = ""
while len(target) < target_length:
    if len(target) >= 2 and random() < prob:
        c = target[-2]
    else:
        c = choice(letters)
    target += c

print(target)
```

Here I just decide about choosing a new letter from the set or getting the letter 2 times before from the existing sequence (string `target`). Of course I have to consider the case when `target` has less than 2 letters, otherwise it's nothing to choose 2 time before.

Comment: Thanks , its working! Never thought it would be this fast :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import random
import string

alpha = string.ascii_uppercase

my_list = [random.choice(alpha) for _ in range(2)]  # initializing; first two elements have to be random

n = 50  # select the length of the list; note that 2 elements are already inside!
for i in range(n):
  if random.random() < 0.2:  # 20% of the time repeat a letter
    my_list.append(my_list[len(my_list)-2])
  else:
    my_list.append(random.choice(alpha))  # 80% of the time, get a new

print(my_list)  # -> ['O', 'M', 'O', 'F', 'B', 'F', 'S', 'G', ...
#                                ^              ^
```

---

And to check:

```
j = 0
for i, item in enumerate(my_list[2:], 2):
  if item == my_list[i-2]:
    j += 1
print(j/len(my_list))  # I got 23%. The bigger the list get's, the closer to 20% you'll get
```

Comment: Thanks , its working! Never thought it would be this fast :)

Comment: I don't understand how to check.. It always tells me 0.. I thought about changing the 2, in : for i, item in enumerate(my_list[2:], 2).. but if I change if for 50, I get list error : index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: Create a random list and get indices that do not fulfil the condition. From those, select random indices to fulfil the condition minus the number of indices already fulfilling it. Set those indices to the element two indices prior.

```
lst = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(20)]
not_same = [i for i in range(2, len(lst)) if i not in same]
num_same = len(lst) - len(not_same)
make_same = random.sample(not_same, len(lst)//5 - num_same)
for i in make_same:
    lst[i] = lst[i-2]
```

Note, however, that there is the chance of getting slightly fewer or slightly more than 20%. If e.g. your list is `[1,2,3,4,1]` and you set `3` to `1`, you gain two "same" elements instead of one, and if the list is `[1,2,3,4,3]` and you set the first `3` to `1`, you gain one and you lose one.